# Randomly selecting item from list using java selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have the following code snippet

```
<div class="space-10"></div>
<form action="/book/index" method="post" class="form-inline" >
<div class="row no-margin no-padding">
<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-12 no-margin-padding">
   <select id="sport" name="sport" data-style="form-control">
      <option value="">Välj sport</option>
      <option value="1" 
         data-content="<i class='ma ma-Tennis'></i> Tennis">Tennis</option>
      <option value="2" 
         data-content="<i class='ma ma-Badminton'></i> Badminton">Badminton</option>
      <option value="3" 
         data-content="<i class='ma ma-Squash'></i> Squash">Squash</option>
      <option value="4" 
         data-content="<i class='ma ma-Bordtennis'></i> Bordtennis">Bordtennis</option>
      <option value="5" 
         data-content="<i class='ma ma-Padel'></i> Padel">Padel</option>
      <option value="6" 
         data-content="<i class='ma ma-Övrigt'></i> Övrigt">Övrigt</option>
      <option value="7" 
         data-content="<i class='ma ma-Pickleball'></i> Pickleball">Pickleball</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

And i want random selection of an item from list. I've tried all possible selectors but getting element not found error.

Comment: You can use Select class with value (write API to generate random number from 1 to 7). This should ideally address your requirement. Could you please share what selectors you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I hope my below code may help you:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("id")));

//Get all options
List<WebElement> dd = dropdown.getOptions();
int index = 0;//if list contains only one element it will take that element
if(dd.size()>1){
   //Get a random number between 1, size of dd
    random rand = new Random();
    index = rand.nextInt(dd.size()-1);
 }else if(dd.size()<1){
    //print error message
     int = -1;
 }
 if (index >= 0){
     dropdown.selectByIndex(index);
 }
```

Comment: Your code misses some checks for `dd.size()` since if `dd.size()-1` would be `<=0` you will get an Exception in `nextInt()`

Comment: my intention is to give an idea of selecting random option, they need to take care of exceptions

Comment: Of course it is up to you how to give the answer. I'm just saying that your code will not work for `size = 1` and it won't take much time to fix.

Comment: it will work for size = 1 , it will take the 0th index element when size is 1

Comment: No, it will not. Have you ever tried to call `new Random().nextInt(0)`? Check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-